# Not able to create source in stripe with type 'sepa_debit'

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe.js

I am trying to integrate the Sepa payment method with a woocommerce store.

In test mode when I try to create the source with type sepa debit,
it gives me following error. The code I am using is as follows and same as in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit).

```
Stripe.source.create({
      type: 'sepa_debit',
      sepa_debit: {
        iban: 'DE89370400440532013000',
      },
      currency: 'eur',
      owner: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
        address: {
          line1: 'Nollendorfstraße 27',
          city: 'Berlin',
          postal_code: '10777',
          country: 'DE',
        },
      },
    }, function(status,response){
        console.log(status);
        console.log(response);
});
```

According to this post [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-sepa-direct-debit-payments-with-stripe):

> SEPA Direct Debit payments are available to Europe-based Stripe users in a closed preview. In order to activate SEPA Direct Debit, you will need to request an invite through your Stripe Dashboard.

However I am not able to find out from where I can request the invite for Sepa Debit in my Stripe Dashboard.

I am based in India so do I need to have a different stripe account? Or am I missing something?

Comment: We just activated our SEPA Direct Debit payments in Stripe under:
https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings [Where to activate Stripe SEPA Direct Debit functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWFl4.jpg) We had it activated within minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Before you can begin accepting SEPA Direct Debit payments, your Stripe account needs to have a few months history of processing card payments.

( source: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit -> in the green header )

Apparently, they also disable this in test mode..

Comment: @Neils , Thanks for the reply, what you mean by they disable in test mode? , cant we test the code before deployment? and if so how Am I supposed to test my code? I appropriate the help

Comment: SEPA requires an invitation through the Dashboard before you can use it to create test payments. For this, you need a history of card payments. I am currently facing the same issue and contacted Stripe about it. They are looking in to it. For now it is not possible to use SEPA in test mode if it is not activated yet.

Comment: hmmm.. my client also have contacted them and as thier account has an history, they said it will take upto 15 days to activate, so need to wait til lthen ..., let me know if you get it activated and test successfully, I will also post any updates here.

Comment: I just found out how to at least get the request invite button to work. You will need to activate the account. When you did that, go to payments -> settings . Now SEPA should be there and you can click request invite. If you have a history of payments, I guess you will be approved in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

For try the [source type](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source) "*sepa_debit*" on an [IBAN Element](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/iban) is indifferent if you are in live or test mode, the only requisite is enable the option "[SEPA Direct Debit](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit)" under [Payment Settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings) section which is based in "invitation list" mode.

[image]

As they write:

> SEPA Direct Debit payments are available to Europe-based Stripe users
> in a closed preview. In order to activate SEPA Direct Debit, you will
> need to request an invite through your Stripe Dashboard.

And as [second condition](https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-sepa-direct-debit-payments-with-stripe):

> Before you can accept SEPA Direct Debit payments, your Stripe account
> needs to have regularly processed card payments for 30 days. SEPA
> Direct Debit payments are also subject to processing volume limits,
> and payments can fail if you exceed your limits. If you are a new
> customer or plan to process a high volume of transactions, please get
> in touch to request a review.

When you get accepted, you can try in live/test mode with your public and secret keys. Until you get accepted, you can use ONLY the public keys as demo which are showed in stripe docs as merchant demo, like for example this key (could be changed in future):

> // Note: this merchant has been set up for demo purposes.
>
> pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh